CMake ensuring tests link to built, not installed library
I have an issue very similar to How can I point C++ tests to my build-directory copy of my library and not to the installed library when LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the installed one? but unrelated to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
In my project, I first create a library using the standard cmake functions. Here is a simplified version:
    # Installation directories
    include(GNUInstallDirs)
    
    # Build library
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        ${SRC_FILES}
    )

    # Definitions
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${DEFINITIONS})

    # Properties
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 20
    )

    # Compile options
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
    )

    # Include directories
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
    )

    # System include directories
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PUBLIC
        ${SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

    # Link libraries
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        ${SYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
    )

I then want to build some tests, which I do through a similar procedure, and link these tests to my library (this CMakeLists.txt is in a test subfolder):
    # Build tests
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests
        ${TEST_SRC_FILES}
    )

    # Definitions
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests PUBLIC ${TEST_DEFINITIONS})

    # Properties
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 20
    )

    # Compile Options
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests PRIVATE
        -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
    )

    # Include Directories
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include>
    )

    # System Include Directories
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests SYSTEM PUBLIC
        ${TEST_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

    # Link Libraries
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests PUBLIC
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${TEST_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
    )

    # Enable ctest
    enable_testing()
    add_test(NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}_tests COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}_tests)

When I build, everything is great. The tests link to my library and life is good. If I examine the executable with ldd I see:
libmycoolproject.so => /home/username/src/mycoolproject/build/libmycoolproject.so (0x00007ffd2c8c3000)

And with readelf -d:
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmycoolproject.so]
 ... (more libraries)
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/username/src/mycoolproject/build:/usr/local/lib:/home/username/src/mycoolproject/build/gtest/lib]

Note that one of the system libraries I depend on lives in /usr/local/lib.
However as soon as I install my library with sudo make install, ldd tells me:
libmycoolproject.so => /usr/local/lib/libmycoolproject.so (0x00007ffb480b3000)

The problem is then that if I make local changes, build, and run my tests, the tests link to the installed library rather than the one in my build folder.
How can I ensure that my tests link with the build directory version at runtime? What is going on here with the link order / RUNPATH?
Things I've tried without successful result:

putting BUILD_RPATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} in set_target_properties
appending to CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH
changing the order of the libraries in target_link_libraries
linking against ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.so instead of ${PROJECT_NAME}


"What is going on here with the link order / RUNPATH" - RUNPATH order is described in that question. It seems you have LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable being set to /usr/local/lib, so this search path have preference over any RUNPATH entry. You may explicitly empty LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable when run your test by using the approach in that answer. However, I am not sure that unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH won't break the search for other libraries needed for your test.

Funny enough, that property name BUILD_RPATH implies RPATH setting and not RUNPATH one. CMake actually passes -rpath option to the linker... But the linker could interpret it as request for RUNPATH. See e.g. that question. You may try to specify -Wl,--disable-new-dtags in CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS for avoid such linker's behavior.

@Tsyvarev regardless of if /usr/local/lib is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or not, I still want /usr/local/lib in my RUNPATH so that one of the other system libraries can be found. So perhaps explicitly putting the build folder in RPATH with those linker flags as you suggest may be the answer. I will try it, but I also don't know the full consequences of --disable-new-dtags. Thanks for your suggestion

SInce it almost never make sense to link unittests to the installed version, I suggest to use static linkage.

Following @Tsyvarev's comment, I was able to enforce link priority with the built library with:
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests PUBLIC
    -Wl,--disable-new-dtags
)

I didn't actually need BUILD_RPATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} in set_target_properties. My understanding is that RPATH is checked before LD_LIBRARY_PATH so /usr/local/lib is checked later. Note also that the order of RPATH in the executable must have the build directory before the installation directory (e.g. as a test BUILD_RPATH /usr/local/lib puts the directory at the start of RPATH and leads to bad linking).
